# Forge 1.12.2-14.23.5.2838 mcmod.info not load correctly

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have provide mcmod.info for my mod, but after run Minecraft Client in IntelliJ, the mod surely loaded, but it cannot load mcmod.info correctly. At the startup process of Minecraft Client, one warning showed:

> [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Mod testforge is missing the required element 'version' and no fallback can be found. Substituting '1.0'.

And after I go into the mod button and look up the mod info, my mod show up in the mod list, but it show something below:

> testforge
>
> Version:1.0
>
> Mod State: Available
>
> No mod information found
>
> Ask your mod author to provide a mod mcmod.info file

I have tried many thing to debug it, but all of them failed.

#### What I have tried:

1. I have unzipped the built jar file and the mcmod.info correctly placed in the root folder.
2. I have put my mcmod.info to json validator and it said the content is correct.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'


version = "1.0.0"
group = "com.galaxy.forge"
archivesBaseName = "Test Forge"

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8'
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

minecraft {
    version = "1.12.2-14.23.5.2838"
    runDir = "run"
    mappings = "snapshot_20171003"
}

dependencies {

}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

**src/main/resources/mcmod.info**

```
[{
  "modid": "testforge",
  "name": "TestForge",
  "description": "Test description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "mcversion": "1.12.2",
  "url": "minecraftforge.net/",
  "authorList": ["GalaxyIT"],
  "credits": "I'd like to thank anyone who can help me >.<"
}]
```

**src/main/java/com/galaxy/forge/testforge/TestForge.java**

```java
package com.galaxy.forge.testforge;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

@Mod(modid = "testforge", useMetadata = true)
public class TestForge {
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that your gradle file excludes `mcmod.info`? If fact it both includes and excludes it on different lines. Try remove exclusion and see what happens.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Everything is still the same. The **build.gradle** file was provided by the forge Mdk, and I only changed **"version" "group" "archivesBaseName "**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must modify the `@Mod` annotation in TestForge.java. You missed the **mod version** but the FML get it from `mcmod.info` and uses it.

For this reason only a warning is throw.

To fix it you must add to `@Mod(modid="testforge",useMetadata=true)` the parameter 
    `version="1.0.0"` resulting `@Mod(modid="testforge",useMetadata=true,version="1.0.0")`